# Como colocar uma camada colorida por cima de uma imagem?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

```css
div {
  background: #000;
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <div></div>
  <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/11909170_999395153465997_38853384_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTA1NTI1MTUxNDA0OTkxNDkyMg%3D%3D.2" alt="">
</span>
```

Ilustração:

**Foto sem fundo colorido:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Foto com fundo colorido**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha gambiarra até funcionou, mas queria aprender do modo certo.

Comment: Cara, isso é uma característica da imagem, você precisa edita-la utilizando GIMP, Photoshop..., para conseguir esse efeito. Você também precisa "colorir" o fundo do elemento "pai", onde a imagem está contida. Mas aparentemente você já está fazendo isso. Então, seu problema é com a imagem mesmo.

Comment: @mauhumor as imagens acima é só pra ilustrar o que eu quero fazer com o css.

Comment: O que você quer fazer exatamente? Que a imagem pegue o "fundo do teu site"? ou você quer colocar uma camada semitransparente em cima da imagem?

Comment: Quero que a imagem fique com um background por cima dela.

Comment: Então, este é o "jeito certo" creio eu. É assim que fazem quando mostram uma imagem, ou propaganda, bloqueando o resto do site. Mas ainda deixando visível. Se você quer que a imagem pegue o que está embaixo. Ai teria que editar, como já falei antes.

Comment: @mauhumor, não é necessário editar a imagem no photoshop, ele consegue facilmente dar esse efeito na imagem como mostrado em minha resposta :)

Comment: No meu entendimento *background* é o que fica por trás, no seu caso é um "*background* na frente"? Não quer editar a pergunta e deixar isso mais claro?

Comment: Ele utilizou o termo errado, queria uma camada na frente, já estava fazendo, mas estava achando a forma não muito boa.

Comment: Galera, muito obrigado pelas as respostas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta utilizar as propriedades `:before` ou `:after`, no caso, seria melhor o `:after` por exemplo, o seu código ficaria assim:

CSS

```
span{
        position:relative;
    }
    div{
        width: 640px;
        height: 640px;
        opacity: 1;
        position: absolute;
    }
    div:after{
        content:'';
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    }
    div img{
        width:100%;
    }
```

HTML

```
<span>
  <div>
     <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/11909170_999395153465997_38853384_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTA1NTI1MTUxNDA0OTkxNDkyMg%3D%3D.2" alt="">
  </div>
</span>
```

Agora, para explicar melhor, as propriedades `:before` e `:after` servem para que possamos controlar um único elemento como se fossem camadas dele, antes e depois, o `:after` foi colocado como absoluto para podermos usar a posição de acordo com `top,left,right e bottom`, o `span` tem de ser setado como relativo, pois como deve saber, o `position absolute` responde ao primeiro pai que for `relativo`.
Então para setar a propriedade `:before/:after` precisamos dizer, qual o conteúdo, daí o `content:'';` para mostrar que o conteúdo é vazio e a propriedade ser apresentada ao usuário final da forma correta, então dou um `background-color` no `after`, e já coloco a `opacidade` junto com o `rgba(0~255,0~255,0~255,0~1)`.

É como se criasse no photoshop uma `layer` por cima do seu elemento, e desse a ela propriedades comuns a um elemento

Answer (score 7):

Além das soluções que apresentaram, pode usar a técnica de [múltiplos *backgrounds*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds), basta usar [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) passando dois valores de cores *rgba* junto à url da imagem:

```css
div {
  height: 262px;
  width: 389px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0,0,0,.3),rgba(0,0,0,.3)
    ),
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VvBr.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Outro exemplo:

```css
div {
  height: 262px;
  width: 389px
}

div.red {
  background:
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(255,0,0,.3),rgba(255,0,0,.3)
    ),
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VvBr.jpg) no-repeat
} 

div.green {
  background:
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0,255,0,.3),rgba(0,255,0,.3)
    ),
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VvBr.jpg) no-repeat
}

div.blue {
  background:
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0,0,255,.4),rgba(0,0,255,.4)
    ),
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VvBr.jpg) no-repeat
}
```

```html
<div class='red'></div>
<div class='green'></div>
<div class='blue'></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Se sua imagem tiver partes transparentes basta setar o `background` normalmente:

```css
#a{background:orange}
#b{background:green}
#c{background:blue}
```

```html
<img id="a" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/162a62cf2058d7dd8d549dd6bd3b46f9">
<img id="b" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/162a62cf2058d7dd8d549dd6bd3b46f9">
<img id="c" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/162a62cf2058d7dd8d549dd6bd3b46f9">
```

Answer (score 4):

A sua "gambiarra" funcionou para o seu teste, porque a imagem e a `div` estão no mesmo tamanho, experimente trocar de imagem. Vai ficar um quadrado cinza em volta da imagem. Isso porque você setou as propriedade na `div` que a imagem está e não na imagem propriamente dita. Veja:

```css
div {
  background: #000;
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <div></div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VvBr.jpg" alt="">
</span>
```

Isso funciona, se a imagem tiver o mesmo tamanho. Agora veja se você colocar a propriedade `filter: brightness(50%);` na imagem, independente do tamanho da `div` ela vai funcionar com o efeito que você quer. Veja:

```css
img {
    filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<span>
  <div></div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VvBr.jpg" alt="">
</span>
```

A propriedade `brightness` ajusta o brilho da imagem. Você pode ver a compatibilidade dos filtros nesse [site](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode setar a propriedade de `background-color`, mas ela fará diferença se a imagem não sobrepor toda a área do background:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style> 
            body {  
                background-image: url("img_tree.gif"), url("img_flwr.gif");
                background-color: #dddddd;
                opacity: 0.5;
                filter: alpha(opacity=50);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Uma melhor solução seria a utilização da propriedade Opacidade/Transparencia:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            img {
                opacity: 0.5;
                filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Image Transparency</h1>
        <p>The opacity property specifies the transparency of an element. The lower  the value, the more transparent:</p>

        <p>Image with 50% opacity:</p>
        <img src="img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" width="170" height="100">

    </body>
</html>
```

Consulte mais:

- [CSS Opacity/Transparency](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)
- [CSS Backgrounds](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

Comment: desconhecia tal propriedade (filter), muito bom :)

Comment: Não esqueça de mencionar a compatibilidade dos filtros: [can I use css filters?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)

Comment: Não conhecia essa propriedade. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.