# Como mudar imagem ao clicar?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com um trabalho do curso e tive a seguinte ideia:

Existe várias imagens que vão representar as cadeiras de um cinema(todas são as mesmas imagens, as mesmas estão no meu arquivo HTML), e eu quero fazer o efeito de quando o usuário clicar em uma delas ela mude de cor simbolizando que ele escolheu aquela cadeira.

Eu quero que seja utilizado o "onClick" para que ele chame outra imagem ao clicar nas imagens que estão aparecendo para o usuário ou seja ele vai chamar a mesma imagem só que de cor diferente.

Quero que seja por esse método porém não sei se é possível, se não for me mostre a melhor maneira possível de se fazer isso.

Meu arquivo HTML

```
<div>

    <img src="imagens/cadeiraAzul.png" id="cadeira1" onclick="">

</div>
```

Meu arquivo JS

```js
function cor(){
  
  
  
  }
```

Como sou iniciante nessa área provavelmente vão ter ferramentas desconhecidas por mim então se poder explicar o que cada uma faz ficarei mais agradecido ainda.

Preciso também que se o usuário clicar novamente ele mude para imagem que estava inicialmente, para se caso ele estiver escolhido por engano.

Comment: Nesse seu método, é só alterar o atributo `src` da imagem. Utilize o método `setAttribute('src', 'caminhoDaNovaImagem')`. Detalhe, se você quer "varias cadeiras" no HTML, fique atento ao `id` de cada imagem, pois ID é único, não pode repetir.

Comment: Nesse caso onde eu utilizaria o "setAttribute" ?

Comment: Na sua função do `onclick`. Veja mais informações aqui [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp).

Comment: Nessa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176928/51124) tem várias respostas legais que você pode usar na sua aplicação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode deixar cada estilo em classes diferentes, e então mudar a classe conforme o clique, usando a propriedade [className](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp) do javascript.

Nesse exemplo, deixei como um "toggle", pois o usuário pode selecionar e descelecionar a cadeira:

```js
function marcar(e) {
  // verifica se a classe azul (estilo css que conter a imagem azul) esta no elemento
  if (e.className == "azul") {
    e.className = "vermelho";
  } else {
    e.className = "azul";
  }
}
```

```css
.azul::after {
  content: url("http://recursos.mytime.com.br/Imagem/Menu/247/Azul.gif");
}
.vermelho::after {
  content: url("https://www.deliciouslingerieplus.com.br/image/cache//cores/cor-vermelha-30x30.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="azul" id="cadeira1" onclick="marcar(this)">
  <img class="azul" id="cadeira2" onclick="marcar(this)">
  <img class="azul" id="cadeira3" onclick="marcar(this)">
</div>
```

A ação `onclick` irá passar para função o escopo do elemento que foi clicado. Para deixar o código mais limpo, ao invés de deixar as imagens no source (src), deixei em classes específicas, que chamei de "azul" e "vermelho". Quando for clicado na imagem, verificamos se o elemento em questão (`e`, passado por parâmetro) possui a classe azul (`e.className == 'azul'`) - se sim, ele substitui pela classe `.vermelha`, que contém a imagem vermelha.

Comment: Era exatamente desse jeito que eu queria que fosse, obrigado.Mas poderia explicar parte por parte? Pois continuou sem entender como você fez.

Comment: Só não entendi a necessidade de colocar o "e" entre parênteses depois do nome da função e também o por quê você colocou "this" dentro do parêntese na tag da imagem.Teria como explicar por favor ?

Comment: O `this` envia como argumento o elemento em questão, no caso o `img` que foi clicado. A função precisa receber esse elemento, por isso o `marcar(e)` - o `e` é o elemento em si, isto é, o `img`. Experimente colocar `console.log(e)` logo depois das chaves que inicia a função. Vai ser listado todos os atributos do `img`.

Answer (score 4):

Caso queira aprender um pouco mais sobre o framework Jquery.
Aqui está a implementação rodando da sua dúvida no [fiddle](http://%20https://fiddle.jshell.net/uvtch9az/#&togetherjs=a8JA4Auo1c).

HTML:

```
<p>
    <img alt="" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Flag_of_Italy.svg" 
            style="height: 85px; width: 198px" id="imgBandeira"  />
</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#imgBandeira").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("src") == "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Flag_of_Italy.svg") 
      $(this).attr("src","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/Flag_of_Brazil.svg");
    else
      $(this).attr("src","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Flag_of_Italy.svg");

  });
});
```